# Range.Style change depending on languages

Tags: excel, vba

I just did a macro that changes style depending on something in the English version of Office.

Now I opened in a Spanish version and it does not work.

It turns out that `.Style ="Bad"` now is `.Style ="Incorrecto"` and so on.

How can I set a style that works in any language?

Is there a collection of styles I can handle by index?

Comment: There is a [styles collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa224476(v%3Doffice.11)), though not sure in different languages, there would still be the same style by same index?

Comment: good question @DarXyde, I'll find out later. By now, I just defined my own styles and move on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to ensure consistency across multiple languages, you could add a custom style to the sheet. This custom style should not change based on the user's language.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add(Name:="Some_Name") 
 .Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlDouble 
 .Font.Bold = True 
 .Font.Name = "Calibri" 'This is any font name, but you might check that it is same across different user languages.
End With 
Worksheets(1).Range("A25:A30").Style = "Some_Name"
```

This is a workaround, but once defined it should be just as easy to use. Best of luck!